# ng-click doesn't fire when added post load

Tags: angularjs, translation, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to do a [variable replacement](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/docs/en/#/guide/06_variable-replacement) while also making it clickable with [ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch.directive%3angClick).

I made a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTAgyil7LsK2AUFqQvao?p=preview) (click the button and observe that the input box stays unchanged)

Markup:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" id="input" name="input" ng-model="myValue" test>
  <p translate="VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT" translate-values="{{ 'translationData' }}"></p>
  <p ng-bind-html="alink"></p>
</body>
```

Angular stuff:

```
var translations = {
  VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT: 'Hi, {{name}}'
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ngSanitize']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // add translation table
  $translateProvider.translations(translations);
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.translationData = { name: 'foo'};

  $scope.setValue = function(value) {
    $scope.myValue = value;
  };
}]);

app.directive('test', ['$translate', '$sce', function ($translate, $sce) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
        var a = $translate('VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT', {
          name: '<button type="button" ng-click="setValue(\'foobar\')">click me</button>'
        });
        scope.alink = $sce.trustAsHtml(a);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The question is: Why doesn't `ng-click="setValue('foobar')"` fire when the button is clicked. It's supposed to set the value 'foobar' in the input field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the meanwhile there is an official solution to that problem:

```
<p translate="varWithDirective" translate-compile></p>
```

would do the compilation without the need of writing a custom directive.

For more info:
https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/184

Answer (score 10):

Angular doesn't `$compile` the `$sce` markup.  So Angular hasn't processed your `ng-click` and attached the directive to it.

In order to use Angular directives inside your string, and have them live, you'll need to send the string to Angular's `$compile` function.

One easy way to do this is to use the following directive (found here:https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4992)

Using this you'll replace:

```
<p ng-bind-html="alink"></p>
```

with

```
<p compile="alink"></p>
```

And add this directive:

```
angularApp.directive('compile', function($compile) {
  // directive factory creates a link function
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {
        // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
        return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
      },
      function(value) {
        // when the 'compile' expression changes
        // assign it into the current DOM
        element.html(value);

        // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
        // scope.
        // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
        // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    );
  };
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You created an element outside of angular. I'm not sure how pascalprescht works but you're going to need to tell the element to $compile ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile))