# Rendering directives within $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've included a Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vqV8toHo0vNjtfICtzI?p=preview

I'm trying to add a button to the DOM and when clicked should execute the function bound to it. In this case it should alert "testing". Here is the code.

controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button ng-click="testAlert()">Submit</button>');  

        $scope.testAlert = function () {
            alert('testing')
        };
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358140/ng-click-doesnt-fire-when-added-post-load

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$sce.trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html` are not meant to build HTML with directives.  This technique will not work.

This is because angular works by first compiling and then linking.  See the [conceptual overview](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) for a good explaination.

In short, by the time you link the HTML defined in your `trustAsHtml`, it is too late for angular to compile (and therefore understand) the `ng-click` directive.

In order to dynamically add HTML, you should be looking at the `$compile` service (and/or directives).  [Docs are here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile).

Comment: Right, Here's a new plunker showing how this was achieved with $compile. http://plnkr.co/edit/3CewDscih8diAo4mMSwJ?p=preview



Here are some other resources that helped me solve this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database

Comment: Is this possible when building a row in a table and injecting html that contains the keyword dynamic directive?

Comment: I wish you showed how to solve the problem specifically.

Answer (score 12):

For Angular 1.6.1, I found a solution that worked for me.

template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(content);" init-bind> </div>
```

In controller:

```
    $scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
    };
```

Directive:

```
.directive('initBind', function($compile) {
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function (scope, element, attr) {
            attr.$observe('ngBindHtml',function(){
                if(attr.ngBindHtml){
                     $compile(element[0].children)(scope);
                }
            })
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: This also is a solution if anyone willing to try.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Great use of directives and $compile. Thank you!