# Popover not working with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to dynamically load pop over on lable my code was

```
$scope.setStatusMessage = function (message) {
    var lblClass = "", status = "" , template;
        lblClass = "label label-danger";
        status = "failed";
    template = '<label popover="' + message + '" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="' + lblClass + '">' + status + '</label>';
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(template);
}
```

my html was

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="setStatusMessage(statusMessage)"></span>
```

problem is html code is working but popover not working. may i know the problem with fix.

thanks

## UPDATED

OK guys here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3z4ce5s8YorADjgS2mx?p=preview)

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: no nothing. on my browser console.

Comment: can you create any fiddle for better understanding

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623118/rendering-directives-within-sce-trustashtml

Comment: Ruben Nagoga  - No mate it's not

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe Are you doing this inside a controller? Can you shed more lights on when you are doing this? How dynamic you need it?

Comment: PSL please check the pluker

Comment: Is there a specific reason for why you don't add `label` directly in your HTML instead of using `$sce`? i.e. `<label popover="{{item.message}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="label label-danger">{{item.message}}</label>`

Comment: To be honestly this exame isn't the use on my actual code it much complex than this. I just focused on the pop over not showing issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some workaround: http://plnkr.co/edit/pferF3otkczQo9TJbKck?p=preview

```
directive('compileHtml', function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            messageFn: '&',
            message: '='
          },
          link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.$watch('message', function(message) {
              var html = scope.messageFn({'message': message});
              iElement.html(html);
              $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);
            });
          }
        }
      });
```

Actually it is similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623118/rendering-directives-within-sce-trustashtml), as I said in comments. So you need to compile HTML one more time after inserting HTML into tag.

So I have create directive `compileHtml` you should pass function which returns sanitized HTML (`message-fn` in code) and also provide params for that function (`message` in code). Directive watch for changes of `message` update HTML and re-run compile.

**UPDATE**

Here is fork of your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uhQbzQoon4NqODeZFsuK?p=preview)

In my humble opinion, it is better to create directive which will `$watch` over message, sanitize it without any external function and re-compile.

Comment: can't we compile HTML on controller

Comment: You can compile on controller, but it is not good practice to $watch and work with HTML element in controller.

Comment: OK that'll  be acceptable with few changes message attribute actually not need. we can have it without it. here is the updated one.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3z4ce5s8YorADjgS2mx?p=preview