# Directive inside ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which works perfectly. (it counts down form a number of seconds given as a attribute)

But when I put a piece of HTML-string containing that directive inside another HTML element it does not work; the directive does not compile.
eg.

```
//does not work -> niels-timer-rirective does not compile
JS: $scope.binder = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span niels-timer seconds-to-go="123"></span>');
HTML: <span ng-bind-html="binder"></span>
```

See 'test 4' in this plunk: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kwASEV8YXiNyktzdVQWB?p=preview

Of course this does work

```
HTML: <span niels-timer seconds-to-go="123"></span>
```

Can someone help me?!

Thx:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623118/rendering-directives-within-sce-trustashtml

Comment: won't work, as has been pointed out in multiple questions on this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)