# AngularJS: Can't call onClick() when using ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

I want to handle an onClick() event from generated by ng-bind-html.

I tried some ways but still didn't find a solution. Any help will be appriciated.

```
<html ng-app="Demo">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('Demo', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.memo = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#" ng-click="close();">Binding html</a>');
    $scope.close = function() {
      alert("close clicked");
    };
  }]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div><a href="#" ng-click="close();">No binding html</a></div> <!-- This is OK -->
  <div ng-bind-html="memo"></div> <!-- My question is here. I can't call close() -->
</body>
</html>
```

---

Upadte 1

I think this question is relevant.

[How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)

---

Update 2

Fixed it thanks to user2341963 but I'm not sure why it works...

```
<html ng-app="Demo">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('Demo', [])
  .directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
          ele.html(html);
          $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.memo = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#" ng-click="close();">Binding html</a>');
    $scope.close = function() {
      alert("close clicked");
    };
  }]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="close();">No binding html</a>
  </div>
  <div dynamic="memo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$compile` instead. See [Rendering directives within $sce.trustAsHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623118/rendering-directives-within-sce-trustashtml)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it right now.

Comment: @user2341963 fixed it somehow thanks to you. I can accept your answer if you post your answer. You can just write "see above my comment".

Comment: No need, rather upvote the answer that helped you

Comment: Cool. I appreciate it